# How to fold all code between {{{ and }}} in vim

Tags: vim, folding

I have a lot of code like this

```
#{{{
code here
#}}}

#{{{
more code here
#}}}

etc...
```

I want to fold all of them instead of going to each `#{{{` line and type `zfa{`.

I read the vim documentation and tried typing `set foldmethod={{{` but I got the error `E474: Invalid argument: foldmethod={{{` .

What do I press on my keyboard to tell vim to fold all code between `#{{{` and `#}}}`?

And what do I press to expand them all again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your vimrc add the option `set foldmethod=marker`. Then to fold you type `zm` and to unfold type `zr`.

Comment: thanks.  I didn't want my code to be collapsed by default when I open the document. So I didn't put `set foldmethod=market` in my vimrc.  Instead, I typed it when I need to collapse all region.

Answer (score 13):

The `foldmethod` option is not for setting the fold marker.
You can set up fold markers by doing something like this:

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker={{{,}}}
```

As for vim's folding shortcuts, this article on the vim tips wiki is very helpful.
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding

For more help on folding, you can do `:help folding` inside of vim.
For help on the keyboard shortcuts for folding, do `:help fold-commands`